# Conditional SELECT based upon IF EXISTS in MySql

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements, where-clause

There is a table users. Based upon 2 column data  I need to select rows.

Let say these 2 columns are **ID** and **ID_API**.

So while fetching data, I need to search 1st if for a given value exists in ID_API column, then SELECT that row.
Else use ID in WHERE condition.

Here is What is look like

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID_API= '12345')
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID_API= '12345'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID_= '12345'
END
```

How to manage it?

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, you can look for rows that have `ID_API = 12345`, or rows that have `ID = 12345` *as long as* there is no row with `ID_API = 12345`:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE ID_API = '12345' OR
      ID = '12345' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID_API = '12345')
```

In the special case where there is only one row per user, you can do that by searching for either `ID_API = 12345` or `ID = 12345`, then ordering results by `ID_API = 12345` descending (since that will return a value of 1 if it is true) and using `LIMIT 1` to restrict to 1 row.

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE ID_API = '12345' OR ID = '12345'
ORDER BY ID_API = '12345' DESC
LIMIT 1
```